# Undefined index: retail_price displayed i couldn't pass retail_price in to loading_add.php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating an inventory control system for my sales. i can serialize complete table successfully i have one problem i have sell_price column in in table, retail price column is not there in the table.how can send the retail price hidden to the php page.because i need to calculating profit at end the day sales. i am sending all record to loading_add.php page through ajex. what i tried so far i wrote it below. how to send retail_price hidden field in to loading_add.php page.

**Enter the product code the get the product prices.only display sell price. retail should display the hidden field.**

**this is the Form design**

```
 <td>
      <select class="form-control" id="product_id" name="product_id" required>
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
       </select>
     </td>

      <td>
  <input type="hidden" class='retailprice'  id="retail_price" name="retail_price" >
      <input type="text" class="form-control sell_price" id="sell_price" name="sell_price" placeholder="price" disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="number" class="form-control sell_price" id="qty" name="qty" placeholder="qty" min="1" value="1"  required>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="total_cost" id="total_cost" name="total_cost" disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="addproduct()">Add
        </button>
      </td>
```

**Get the price**

```
function getPrice() {
        $("#pro_price").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../php/product/get_price.php',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {product_id: $("#product_id").val() },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#sell_price").val(data[0].sell_price);
                current_stock =Number(data[0].qty);
                $("#qty").focus();
                retail_price =Number(data[0].retail_price);
                pro_price =Number(data[0].sell_price);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            }
        });
    }
```

**After get product name and price click add putton product add in to the table** 
**Add the product in the table**

```
function addproduct() {
var product = {
    cat_id: $("#cat_id option:selected").text(),
    product_name: $("#product_id option:selected").text(),
    product_id: $("#product_id").val(),
   retail_price: $("#retail_price").val(),
    pro_price: $("#pro_price").val(),
    qty: $("#qty").val(),
    total_cost: $("#total_cost").val(),
    button: '<button  type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs")">delete</button>'
};
addRow(product);
$('#frmInvoice')[0].reset();
```

**creating a addRow function add the product in the list**

```
 function addRow(product) {

              var $tableB = $('#product_list tbody');
    var $row = $("<tr><td><Button type='button' name = 'record'  class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' name='record' onclick='deleterow(this)' >Delete</td>" +
    "<td>" + product.product_id + "</td>" +
    "<td class=\"price\">" + product.cat_id + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + product.product_name + "</td>" +
    "<td><input type='hidden' class='retail_price' value="+ product.retail_price +">" + product.pro_price + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + product.qty + "</td><td>"
    + product.total_cost +
    "</td></tr>");
    $row.data("cat_id", product.cat_id);
    $row.data("product_id", product.product_id);
    $row.data("product_name", product.product_name);
    $row.data("price", product.price);
    $row.data("retail_price", product.retail_price);
    $row.data("qty", product.qty);
    $row.data("total_cost", product.total_cost);
    total += Number(product.total_cost);
    $('#total').val(total);
    console.log(product.total_cost);
    $row.find('deleterow').click(function (event) {
        deleteRow($(event.currentTarget).parent('tr'));
    });
    $tableB.append($row);

}
```

**

```
**var table_data = [];
    $('#product_list tbody tr').each(function(row,tr)
    {
        var sub = {
            'product_id' : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
            'cat_id' : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
            'product_name' : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
              'retail_price': $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text(),
            'sell_price' : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),
            'qty' : $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text(),
            'total_cost' : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text(),
        };
        table_data.push(sub);
    });**
```

**

**send the data in to loading_add.php page**

```
  $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: '../php/product/loading_add.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',

        data: {data:table_data},
```

**loading_add.php**

```
$relative_list = $_POST['data'];

        $stm = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sales_product(sales_id,cat_id,product_id,retail_price,sell_price,qty,total,profit)
          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stm->bind_param("issiiiii",$last_id,$cat_id,$product_id,$retail_price,$price,$qty,$total_cost,$profit);
        $cat_id= $relative_list[$x]['cat_id'];
        $product_id= $relative_list[$x]['product_name'];

$retail_price= $relative_list[$x]['retail_price'];
       $price= $relative_list[$x]['price'];
        $qty= $relative_list[$x]['qty'];
        $total_cost= $relative_list[$x]['total_cost'];
```

Comment: You could add it by using $("#pro_price").val() when you ajax to server right? on data:table_data

Comment: i edit the question sir

Comment: Pardon, I still not see anything changed? I only get the point that you want to send the hidden field. When you want to send it to PHP, that means you should get the data by using your function `tabledata`, anyway if you have problem with each row, that means the problem is with the id. ID in a html page only allowed once, change it to the class `<input type='hidden' class='retailprice'>`, and on `retailprice: $($(tr).find('.retailprice')).val()`. It should work. Anyway .find in jquery you could see it here http://api.jquery.com/find/ it's like you did before.

Comment: sir can you correct the above code sir it is way to understand

Comment: Your code is dissapear.. -_- I can't help you if you change the code. My comment already answer your code anyway. You should try it first.

Comment: <input type='hidden' class='retailprice'> if i put i like this it will show on the form design right. i don't want show the form design when the user enter the product code it will display sellprice and product name textbox this retail textbox data should hidden

Comment: No, when you use input type hidden it won't shown on the end user eyes. see this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden

Comment: i will try and let you know sir

Comment: <td>" + product.retail_price + "</td>  this <td> how to hide from the table add the product into table please help me to hide

Comment: 'retail_price': $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text(),   i wrote i like this but data is not passing to loading_add.php  .         undefined index: retail_price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your table rows you can embed the retail_price like this:**

```
"<table>
<tr data-retail-price="'+product.retail_price+'"><td><Button type='button' name = 'record'  class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' name='record' onclick='deleterow(this)' >Delete</td>" +
            "<td>" + product.product_id + "</td><td class=\"price\">" + product.cat_id + "</td><td>" + product.product_name + "</td><td>" + product.sell_price+
            "</td><td>" + product.qty + "</td><td>" + product.total_cost + "</td></tr>
</table>"
```

**And to get the retail price you can use JQuery attrib function:**

```
var sub = {
            'product_id' : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
            'cat_id' : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
            'product_name' : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
              retail_price : $(tr).attr("data-retail-price");
            'sell_price' : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),
            'qty' : $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text(),
            'total_cost' : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text(),
        };
```

Comment: $row.data("retail_price", product.retail_price); is there any think have to change

Comment: You should change this: var $row = $("<tr data-retail-price="'+product.retail_price+'"><td><Button type='button' name = 'record' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' name='record' onclick='deleterow(this)' >Delete</td>" + "<td>" + product.product_id + "</td>" + "<td class=\"price\">" + product.cat_id + "</td>" + "<td>" + product.product_name + "</td>" + "<td><input type='hidden' class='retail_price' value="+ product.retail_price +">" + product.pro_price + "</td>" + "<td>" + product.qty + "</td><td>" + product.total_cost + "</td></tr>");

Comment: 'retail_price': $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').find('.retail_price').text()  i tried the one still Undefined index: retail_price

Comment: use this: `retail_price : $(tr).attr("data-retail-price"); `

Comment: follow my answer and it should be okay

Comment: Undefined index: retail_price in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\sales2\php\product\loading_add.php</b> on line <b>47</b><br />
Column 'retail_price' cannot be null

Comment: follow my answer and it should be okay

Comment: i tred still display Undefined index: retail_price in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\sales2\php\product\loading_add.php</b> on line <b>47</b><br /> Column 'retail_price' cannot be null

Comment: Change this also: `$("#retail_price").val(Number(data[0].retail_price));` inside your ajax request

Comment: i changed Undefined index: retail_price displayed

Comment: Show us your php script

Comment: where is the loading_add.php?

Comment: did you see the script sir

Comment: i want to see the script of this file loading_add.php

Comment: i added it loading_add.php above

Comment: edit this line `$relative_list = json_decode($_POST['data']);`

Comment: put this code above right after $relative_list = json_decode.. $retail_price= $relative_list[$x]['retail_price'];
       $price= $relative_list[$x]['price'];
        $qty= $relative_list[$x]['qty'];
        $total_cost= $relative_list[$x]['total_cost'];

Comment: You are using bind but your variables is not defined. you defined it below